# Grant Login Access to a support orgnanization

Tags: grant-login-access

I want to grant login access to support personnel for a certain AppExchange app (Vision-e). I have already:

1. managed support options to enable login access for the desired from
   Setup > Administer > Security Controls > Login Access Policies, and 
   [image]
2. attempted to Grant Account Login Access from [My Name] > My Settings > Grant Account Login Access.

However, the support from the desired provider does not appear in my personal settings' Grant Account Login Access screen, seen below:[image: personal settings]

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted the question initially, Have you tried switching the support option to `Available to Administrators Only`.

Comment: I have, thank you.  I think I may have found the problem: I am an administrator and so have not been assigned a user license for the app. I will re-provision a license to myself to test.

Comment: @BrentBow Ah, I see you've come to the same conclusion. Pretty sure that that is why you can't grant the login access. You need to be able to access the app with a license.

Comment: Ah good to know, we had similar issue, user with no license were not even able to see anything related to package. Weird part is you were able to see it in support options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [How to Grant Login Access to a Salesforce Success Agent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-Grant-Login-Access-to-a-Salesforce-com-Support-Analyst-1327108337089&language=en_US&type=1):

> You can’t grant access to certain support organizations if your administrator has set up restrictions or a packaged application’s license prevents it.

Check that the user trying to grant login access has a license to the package application in question.

Comment: Your timing is impeccable! (How redundant is my answer now?) Thanks a million, Daniel. Best answer

Comment: @BrentBow It happens :). No problem having two similar answers.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this particular app requires licenses. I needed to assign myself a user license for the installed package to receive support through granting login access (in my case I had to temporarily re-provision one of our user's licenses to my SF User).

To provision yourself a license, navigate to **Setup > Develop > Installed Packages > Manage Licenses** for [the desired app]